# Compilation errors when using NgForm in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a fairly simplistic (so far) form I'm creating using two-way databinding.

```
<form #formModel="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="btnSubmitQuote(formModel)">
    <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
    <input name="name" [(ngModel)]="formModel.name" matInput required>

    <div mat-dialog-actions>/
        <button type="submit"
                mat-flat-button color="primary"
                [disabled]="!formModel.form.valid">
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have a corresponding model that I created to map to the form:

```
export class RequestQuoteModel {
    constructor(public name: string,
                public email: string,
                public phone: number,
                public address: string,
                public city: string,
                public description: string) {
    }
}
```

I'm now running into compilation errors when I run the application:

```
Error: Error: Could not resolve [object Object] / undefined
    at Scope.resolve (D:\Documents\Code\Github\neis-guy-painting-angular\neis-guy-painting\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1323:23)
    at TcbEventHandlerTranslator.TcbExpressionTranslator.resolveTarget (D:\Documents\Code\Github\neis-guy-painting-angular\neis-guy-painting\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1878:35)
    at TcbEventHandlerTranslator.TcbExpressionTranslator.resolve (D:\Documents\Code\Github\neis-guy-painting-angular\neis-guy-painting\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1791:29)
    at TcbEventHandlerTranslator.resolve (D:\Documents\Code\Github\neis-guy-painting-angular\neis-guy-painting\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:2035:45)  
    at AstTranslator.maybeResolve (D:\Documents\Code\Github\neis-guy-painting-angular\neis-guy-painting\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1776:84)
    at AstTranslator.translate (D:\Documents\Code\Github\neis-guy-painting-angular\neis-guy-painting\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\expression.js:74:33)
    at D:\Documents\Code\Github\neis-guy-painting-angular\neis-guy-painting\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\expression.js:201:68
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at AstTranslator.visitMethodCall (D:\Documents\Code\Github\neis-guy-painting-angular\neis-guy-painting\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\expression.js:201:33)
    at MethodCall.visit (D:\Documents\Code\Github\neis-guy-painting-angular\neis-guy-painting\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:8162:28)
[91m    at AstTranslator.translate (D:\Documents\Code\Github\neis-guy-painting-angular\neis-guy-painting\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\expression.js:78:24)
    at Object.astToTypescript (D:\Documents\Code\Github\neis-guy-painting-angular\neis-guy-painting\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\expression.js:55:27)
    at TcbEventHandlerTranslator.TcbExpressionTranslator.translate (D:\Documents\Code\Github\neis-guy-painting-angular\neis-guy-painting\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1776:33)
    at tcbEventHandlerExpression (D:\Documents\Code\Github\neis-guy-painting-angular\neis-guy-painting\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:2017:27)
    at tcbCreateEventHandler (D:\Documents\Code\Github\neis-guy-painting-angular\neis-guy-painting\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1975:23)
    at TcbUnclaimedOutputsOp.execute (D:\Documents\Code\Github\neis-guy-painting-angular\neis-guy-painting\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\typecheck\src\type_check_block.js:1069:39)
```

The first line, `<form #formModel="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="btnSubmitQuote(formModel)">`, seems to be what's causing the errors.

Could this potentially be an issue with Angular Material? I had some issues getting that setup, but can confirm I have a working installation because I can create a button with `<button mat-flat-button color="accent">Start</button>` just fine.

I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: Can you add it to the stackblitz that helps

Comment: Have you defined in your TS formModel as @ViewChild ('formModel') formModel: NgForm?